# Warnings when printing to non-UTF filehandle

Tags: perl, encoding, warnings

I have this code for opening file:

```
use Encode qw(:fallbacks);    
$PerlIO::encoding::fallback = FB_PERLQQ;
open my $log,'>:encoding(cp-1251)','log.txt';
```

Some codes do not map to cp-1251 and I see warnings like '"\x{015f}" does not map to cp1251 at ...'. Is it possible to disable this warning for a specific filehandle? \x{015f} in output file is enough for me.

Comment: @Alexadr, why in the world would you *want* to lose data? Lossy is bad bad bad! This seems fundamentally flawed.

Comment: @tchrist, it is easier to view in FAR, which I use to view log file. And viewing some symbols as \x{015f} in case of log files does not bother me. Of course I use utf8 in output files.

Answer (score 3):

I’d try `no warnings 'layer'`.

Comment: Me, I’d choose a non-lossy encoding!